# Javascript prototype, property and function inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

What is the best way to inherit in JS? JS is always changing and any information you research has a different way to do "class" inheritance. This is the method I use but I only don't like it because it is so ugly. Are there better ways with the same outcome?

```
function Foo(){
 this.doFoo = function(){}
 return this;
}
Foo.prototype = {
   doMoreFoo : function(){
      return 5;
   }
}

function Bar(){
   Foo.call(this);
   // override
   this.doFoo = function(){return 22;}
   return this;
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

Comment: SideNote:  ES6 have classes.  Find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Without classes you can't get inheritance in the same way you would in e.g. Java by using `extends`

Comment: @jmugz I know this, but how widespread is support for ES6? Actually, my client ONLY uses FF and we ask to update to latest. Will this be OK?

Comment: In practice you'll want to use a compiler to compile your ES6 source to ES5, e.g. Babel. If you're going there anyway, use any of the many languages that compile to Javascript, like CoffeeScript, TypeScript etc, which all add nicer inheritance syntax.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having such a ridiculous stack of modules and compilers and this and that on top of JS. I think it creates a huge barrier to an incoming dev who needs to wrap their head around the 45 different modules installed... If I can use ES6 just for the class syntax, I would be happy..